# Usage of "acknowledge"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, politeness

Is it acceptable to write "We acknowledge Dr. AAA for his useful advice" to express gratitude or appreciation?

Comment: Please never just ask “Is this correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's very formal, but it's a valid use of "acknowledge." A warmer way to say it would be "We gratefully acknowledge Dr. AAA for his useful advice." If you prefer not to make Dr. AAA the direct object, you could say "We gratefully acknowledge Dr. AAA's useful advice."

Answer (score 0):

It is not wrong, but it is more polite to "thank Dr X", or "express gratitude to Dr X.".